# .NET 6 Core Razor Page wildcard on root overrules files in wwwroot

Tags: c#, .net, razor-pages

I'm trying to run a .NET 6 web application on a webserver, but the css and js files in wwwroot are unaccessible, due to a wildcard on a pageroute.

Some code snippets:

**Program.cs**

*I stripped some code to make it easier to read, below you see the basic setup, all other code doesn't involve the behavior I experience.*

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddLocalization();
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();

// Add pageroutes using some middleware
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<RazorPagesOptions>, RoutingConfiguration>();

var app = builder.Build();
RewriteOptions rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions();
rewriteOptions.AddRedirectToWww();    
app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// I need to access some file locations on the webserver outside the webapplications folder, so I add some locations like this:
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("C:\\sharedstuff"), 
    RequestPath = PathString.FromUriComponent("/shared")
});

// To enable default behavior for static files, I call this one:
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

**Middleware RoutingConfiguration.cs**

*Also stripped some content for clrearness*

```
public class RoutingConfiguration : IConfigureOptions<RazorPagesOptions>
{
    public void Configure(RazorPagesOptions options)
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/catchall", "/{*input}");
    }
}
```

In the wwwroot folder we find 2 subfolders (/css and /js) containing some css and js files.

When I navigate to /css/site.css, the /catchall page is called with "css/stie.css" as input. But I expected the static css file, that is available in wwwroot/css.

And it's pretty hard to debug, because the problem only exists when running on a webserver, on local it works fine.

Anyone experiencing the same problem? Or does anybody see the problem in my code?

Comment: Instead of stripping possibly important code, create a *minimal* (ie as small as possible) example that compiles and demonstrates the problem. Razor Pages by itself has no such problem, and *adding* extra routes in the normal way doesn't override previous ones. I suspect your code *replaced* all routes with the catch-all. The [routing documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-7.0) shows that custom routes are added inside `AddRazorPages`

Comment: Testing such cases is described in [Integration tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0) using a [WebApplicationFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory). This allows starting the entire WebApplication through a TestServer instance and allows you to customize configuration and services eg to replace some of them with mocks

Comment: Hi @Panagiotis Kanavos, thanks for the suggestions. I tested it piece by piece and the problem appears when I enable the `builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<RazorPagesOptions>, RoutingConfiguration>();` line. I need to use some middleware for this, since the pageroutes to add are in the database. In the middleware I get them from the db and loop through them and call AddPageRoute in the loop.

Comment: I think the most striking thing is that it works locally but not on a webserver.

Answer (score 0):

It works, after a lot of trial and error.

It's a bit weird, but the conclusion was to swap the order of

```
// I need to access some file locations on the webserver outside the webapplications folder, so I add some locations like this:
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("C:\\sharedstuff"), 
    RequestPath = PathString.FromUriComponent("/shared")
});
```

and

```
// To enable default behavior for static files, I call this one:
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

So first call `app.UseStaticFiles();` and then add more specific `StaticFileOptions`.